# How to search projects on github that uses a specific framework?

Tags: search, github

A while ago someone listed "all projects" using tensorflow. How can i do a search query like that on github? Unfortunately i couldn't find this information anymore and Github Search "dorks" didn't really help. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Since this question is not related to coding, it will be closed soon. What kind of projects are you looking for? Check this one: https://github.com/GunhoChoi/Deep-Learning-For-Beginners

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of query for which you would use [Google BigQueries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/).

See examples in "[Using BigQuery to Analyze PHP on GitHub](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/09/using-bigquery-to-analyze-php-on-github)".
If you know how to detect the import and use of a specific framework, you can build a query that will be played on *all* the (public) GitHub repos.